# fingering for a piece

Tags: piano, sheet-music, fingering

I am a self learner on piano, merely from web materials.. I am trying to learn this piece.
https://musescore.com/torbybrand/scores/4561016

I compared the music sheet and the fingering used by the performer on the youtube video.

I have a question on the fingering for the 2nd bar.
[image]

I expected that was a crossing, "left hand finger 1" is on the right side of "right hand finger 1", but in the youtube video,

that was not such situation. I wonder why my expectation was wrong, and how to play this bar correctly. Thanks.

one more question, why the performer in the youtube used the finger 3,1,3,3,3 for right hand but not the below 5,1,5,4,4? is 5,1,5,4,4 bad?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectation was correct. Since the F in the right hand of the thumb is written as a dotted quarter note, it should technically still be playing when that left hand plays the high G.

The performer in the video is using some sustain (either with a pedal or a particular sound) and as such is allowing themselves to be a little sloppy with some of these rhythms. As far as I can tell, they barely hold that right-hand F for an entire eighth note, let alone the dotted quarter that's written.

This is where you get to decide how you want to perform the piece. If you want the sound to be sustained, you can do what's in the video you linked. But if the sound should be more dry, I would personally do what you originally thought. Although I'd make one small change: when moving from G to F in the left hand, I'd actually put finger 2 on the F, and while I'm holding that tied F, I'd change it to finger 1.

Comment: how to do this? some sustain (either with a pedal)? i am confused on the pedal too. when i press 1&3 on the right hand, I hold the pedal, then the sound will be sustained, but a the same time, my left hand is pressing 5 then 2 then 1, so all the sounds (by both hands) will be sustained?

Comment: Most keyboards have particular sounds that have some level of sustain, so you can either create the sense of sustain that way or by using a damper pedal. And yes, if you hold the pedal, then all sounds in both hands will be sustained.

Comment: thanks a lot. i just uploaded one more pic and added one more question, one more question, why the performer in the youtube used the finger 3,1,3,3,3 for right hand but not the below 5,1,5,4,4? is 5,1,5,4,4 bad?

Comment: I would recommend using whatever fingering makes the most sense to you. If I were playing it, I'd play with a third option: 1/3 on the F/C, and then finger 5 on the high F. This way I could smoothly lead from the C to the high F without a break in between.